# Rails + Devise how not to force SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, devise

I have a staging server without valid SSL certificate. So I would like to disable SSL on my rails app to avoid browser warnings. I have tried many things to get it running, but Devise always redirect users to https URL.

My staging environment is the exact copy of my production environment except this line:

`config.force_ssl = false`

I tried to configure devise to force http ([https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-SSL-(HTTPS)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-SSL-%28HTTPS%29)) but it doesn't work either:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?

  def ssl_configured?
    false
  end
end
```

I'm sure i'm missing something...

Comment: So i understand correctly that if you type in url `http://yoursite/users/sign_in` it redirects to https?

Comment: Also which version of Devise do you use?

Comment: I am redirected to https after a signin or a signout. I'm using devise 3.2.4

Comment: Ok, so I think you used wrong part of the guide. Look under the **Devise 3.1** section, theres an example how to enable SSL, not sure how to disable though.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into your **config/environments/staging.rb**

and if you happen to use these lines.. remove them

```
config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl }
config.to_prepare { Devise::RegistrationsController.force_ssl }
config.to_prepare { Devise::PasswordsController.force_ssl }
```

Hope it helps :)